# New .NET Application - Suggestions for simple databasedeployment?

Tags: .net, database, winforms, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am possibly about to embark upon writing a very small .NET Winforms app.
App is a simple calculator tool that will be a giveaway to be bundled with another physical product.
App will install & run standalone on client's pc.. It requires a very simple local database on the same machine that will also need to be installed on the users pc.

Can someone please advise best options for the db.. in terms of :

- Simplicity to deploy
- Keeping costs & licencing low / zero.. ie. no need for user or me to buy a db engine.

Is Access runtime a possibility ? SQL Server seems like overkill.

Thank you,

Bazzaforms

Comment: Why would a calculator need database deployment?

Comment: To store results that are generated by physical device mentioned, and ability to compare with future runs of same device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/),

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world.

There is an official ADO.net adapter [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/).

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case, XML/CSV serialization works fine.

SQLite and Berkeley DB are pretty popular (latter is used by subversion).

Check [Embedded databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database) page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Have ended up going for **SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0** after much investigation, trial & error.

Reaons :

- It is free
- It is lightweight
- It integrates with Visual Studio 2010
- Most importantly, it **Integrates with .NET LINQ to Entity Framework** technology (a tool for this db allows auto generation of edmx file [entity data model]
- It is very easy to deploy (ie. deploy simple dll files)
- It is tried and tested